# Generate Usernames in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file studentlist.txt which reads as follows:

**studentlist.txt**

```
Sam Vimes  
Sam Flynn  
Sam Gamgee  
Sam Carter  
Sam Velo  
Sam Victory  
Sam Vega
```

I have a python program as follows:

```
usernames = []

for line in open('studentlist.txt'):
  count = 1
  name = line.lower().split()
  surname = name[-1]
  username = ''.join(name[0:-1])
  username_w_surname = username + surname[0]
  username_w_surname_integer = username_w_surname + str(count)

  if username not in usernames:
    usernames.append(username)
  elif username_w_surname not in usernames:
    usernames.append(username_w_surname)
  else:
    count = count + 1
    usernames.append(username_w_surname_integer)
for entry in usernames:
  print (entry)
```

Which outputs:

```
sam
samf
samg
samc
samv
samv1
samv1
```

when it was meant to output the following:

```
sam
samf
samg
samc
samv
samv1
samv2
```

**It outputs samv1 instead of samv2**

I am just not sure how this code can be modified to make it work as intended.

Comment: Under what conditions should you increment count? Under what conditions should you reset the count?

Comment: Put the line `count=1` outside the for loop (i.e before it) **Your code is reseting count to 1 for every line.**  Placing `count=1` outside the for loop will actually allow count to increment

Comment: @SruthiV that worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
usernames = []
count = 1 #put countoutside
for line in open('studentlist.txt'):

  name = line.lower().split()
  surname = name[-1]
  username = ''.join(name[0:-1])
  username_w_surname = username + surname[0]
  username_w_surname_integer = username_w_surname + str(count)

  if username not in usernames:
    usernames.append(username)
  elif username_w_surname not in usernames:
    usernames.append(username_w_surname)
  else:
    count = count + 1
    usernames.append(username_w_surname_integer)
for entry in usernames:
  print (entry)


sam
samf
samg
samc
samv
samv1
samv2
```

Comment: Ohh.. that's perfect, that makes sense, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
usernames = []
count = 1

for line in open('studentlist.txt'):
    name = line.lower().split()
    if not name[0] in usernames:
        usernames.append(name[0])
    elif not name[0] + name[-1][0] in usernames:
        usernames.append(name[0] + name[-1][0])
    else:
        usernames.append(name[0] + name[-1][0] + str(count))
        count += 1

for entry in usernames:
    print(entry)
```